# What is the purpose of multi-staged levels in mobile games?

Tags: game-design, mobile, level-design

In most recent mobile games like **Grass Cut**, **FireBalls 3D**, **Twist Hit!** or **Snow Drift!** I see the same level structure where you need to finish **3-4 mini-levels / stages** in order to really finish **the level**.

For example, in **Grass Cut** average time to finish a **full level** that consists from **4 mini-levels / stages is 4 minutes**. That's a very long play session as to mobile. **What's the purpose of those stages?** Why can't they just create a full-featured levels from those stages like in **Color Bump 3D**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mechanical reason to break levels up into multiple parts is to provide a mental break for the player, allowing them to reset their concentration or to provide a clear pausing point for them in case they need to put the game down and attend to other aspects of life.

A similar reason would be to provide more of a sense of accomplishment and progression. Providing goals to complete that are part of a larger goal, even if the scope of both is small, provides both positive reinforcement to the p layer upon completing each smaller goal *and* a bit of a carrot to keep the player engaged when it looks like the *next* goal is close at hand. It helps with that "well I'll just finish *one more* task before I put this down" feeling.

Another reason to break levels up into stages is for thematic reasons, to have a clear transition between environments, ideas, or concepts (but one that still fits within the *overall* theme of the outer level structure). This is more common in narrative-based games; you might also see cutscenes used to break up these stages.